# Python Chess: How to stop chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci() from opening the shell

Tags: python, chess, python-chess

I'm making my own chess GUI and am using python chess and stockfish for it. After freezing it into an executable, every time I call `chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci('location\\of\\stockfish')`, it opens the shell for stockfish and if I close the shell, stockfish stops working. What do I do so that the shell is only running in the background and is not visible to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a platform-specific question and I am guessing from `'location\\of\\stockfish'` that Windows is the platform you are interested in.

`popen_uci` accepts a ** (extra keywords) parameter and you can use that to pass parameters through to `subprocess.Popen()`. Use the passthrough parameter `startupinfo` to provide an instance of `subprocess.STARTUPINFO`. That in turn can set the win32 flag `wShowWindow` to do what you want.

Comment: Yes I do use Windows 10. when i call `chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci('location\\of\\stockfish'startupinfo=subprocess.STARTUPINFO)`,  Im getting the error TypeError: copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @BoarGules answer:

```
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(sf,startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW))
```